# Getting a different order in output from what I expected

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key, keyword-argument

This is my code:

```py
def build_profile(first, last, **user info):
  user_info['first_name'] = first
  user_info['last_name'] = last
  return user_info

user_profile = build_profile('albert', 'einstein', location='princeton', field='physics')

print(user_profile)
```

This is the output I am getting:

```py
{'location': 'princeton', 'field': 'physics', 'first_name': 'albert', 'last_name': 'einstein'}
```

This is my expected output:

```py
{'first_name': 'albert', 'last_name': 'einstein', 'location': 'princeton', 'field': 'physics'}
```

Comment: what is your expectation?

Comment: You need to explain what you think is "expected conventionally". It isn't obvious to us because *we* expect Python dicts to have the keys ordered in insert sequence, and your code is adding `first` and `last` to a pre-existing dict containing the other keys.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by 'conventionally' you mean that you expect the insertion order of the key-value to be preserved.

There are two issues to be aware of.

First of all, in your code the dictionary  `user_info` gets created when you call the function and, at that point, contains only `location` and `field`. The function subsequentially adds `first_name` and `last_name.` Hence, the order is preserved, but maybe not in the way you expected.

More importantly, the Python language does not make any promises about the order in which key value pairs are stored in the dictionary. On the contrary, you should assume that the insertion order is not preserved, even though for small dictionaries it is.

Comment: Up to Python 3.6, `dict` order was an implementation detail. From Python 3.7, `dict`s are *guaranteed* to be in insertion order.

Comment: That teaches me to answer questions while I've been away too long ;-) Thanks

Comment: But before the user_info gets created, the first_name and last_name have been asingned as keys since we have them first as arguments before location and field.

Comment: No, the code in the function only gets executed after the function has been called. It is not executed when the function is created. So, user_dict is created when the function is called with keys location and field. In the function body the keys first_name and last)name are then added when the body is executed.